# Get Key State Function with out using DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, pinvoke

I need codes for vb.net Getkeystate Function() without using any DLL.I'm beginner for API Conversion from vb to vb.net.In vb6 they using user32 DLL.In Vb.Net i need to call Getkeystate Function without that "User32.dll" function. can any one post me the codes without using dll?
Is there any way to get key state without using that dll Getkeystate function in vb.net..? if equivalent is any one know means show me that codes.that codes should be work with in .net framework.

## vb:

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
Dim keystate As Long
keystate = GetKeyState(27)
MsgBox keystate
```

## vb.net

```
Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Dim KeyState As Long
KeyState = GetAsyncKeyState(17)
MsgBox(KeyState
```

Comment: What kind of application? WPF, WinForms, Console?

Comment: Windows Application(To get escape key state)

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to ask for a no-DLL solution because that's exactly what it takes.  Your declaration is wrong, get the right one at pinvoke.net

Comment: oops the above codings are working for me.here I'm showing example codes that's it.but in my project i'm declared properly.it's working.

Comment: Your application already uses user32. You can't interact with the user without it. You should learn some of the basics of windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You either need to call the windows API or not - and I'm not sure from your question you understand what using the DLL/invoking the windows API means. User32.dll is part windows and calling a function within it is actually asking windows to perform function for you. Do you want to replace the function or merely convert the call to vb.net?*

If all you need to just convert the call to vb.net you can use a [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetKeyState) call to the windows API.

here's a sample from that page:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError := True, CharSet := CharSet.Unicode)> _
Private Function GetKeyState (ByVal nVirtKey As KeyStates) As Short
End Function

Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public Class MinhaNovaTextbox
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

    Dim bInserting As Boolean = True

    Private Declare Function GetKeyState _
        Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Short) As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        bInserting = GetKeyState(Keys.Insert)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyPress(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
        bInserting = GetKeyState(Keys.Insert)
        If Not bInserting Then
            Me.SelectionLength = 1
        End If
        MyBase.OnKeyPress(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: hi preet... I don't  want that Dll import and all.The codes should be work with in the .net framework. with out using dll Getkeystate function.is there any equivalent in vb.net for dll Getkeystate function.that is i'm asking... How can i get key state without using that dll function.

Comment: Why don't you want to use that function?

Answer (score 1):

For 17, the Control (Ctrl) key, use `My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown`.

You can also use `System.Windows.Forms.Control.ModifierKeys` or use the `Keyboard` class. But, it is much easier to use the `My` namespace.

For 27, The Escape (Esc) key, you must use the Windows API call. See `GetKeyState` function at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301.aspx

Checking for Esc is not really needed with a System.Windows.Form.Form. Just add a "cancel" button and set the form's `CancelButton` property. If you need more control, then handle the one of the Key events; `KeyUp`, `KeyDown`, `KeyPress`, or `PreviewKeyDown`.

Comment: I am using Windows Application to Get Escape Key State.

Comment: @R1, use the link in the answer.

Comment: Missico.. i'm already visited that page. there is answer. but they using DLL import User32.dll. is there any way to get the Escape(27) Key state with out using that dll...? is it possible in framework..?

Comment: i don't know how to implement that key state for escape Key with out using that dll function.

Comment: @R1, for Escape state, you must use GetKeyState. It is possible to get the Escape key press as I have described. Even .NET Framework relies on Windows API calls. Try using the Key events provided. You should be able to do what is needed through these events. If not, then you must use the GetKeyState API call.

Comment: AMissico very thanks for your comments.now i'm going to use API for Escape Key. With out that dll Getkeystate function i can't find any equivalent.that function only reduce my codes.Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key)
```